# Total Differential of Chemical Potential

Tags: thermodynamics, free-energy, chemical-potential

I have seen many sources (for example this [libretext](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Millersville_University/CHEM_341-_Physical_Chemistry_I/07%3A_Mixtures_and_Solutions/7.03%3A_Chemical_Potential)) cite that the total differential of chemical potential is
$$d\mu = V_m dP - S_m dT$$
where $V_m$ is the molar volume and $S_m$ is the molar entropy. The usual justification for this formula is that chemical potential is the same as partial molar Gibbs free energy, but I was hoping that someone could make this connection more clear. My understanding is that partial molar quantities are quite literally the rate of change of a certain quantity with respect to the number of moles of a substance (please correct me if this understanding is incorrect), so saying that molar Gibbs free energy and chemical potential are the same seems purely definitional and I don't see what conclusions can be drawn from that claim or how that can be used to derive this relationship.

Comment: It's *Gibbs'* not Gibb's.  The chemical potential of a species tells you by how much the free energy changes if you alter the amount of that species while holding everything else constant. This is useful for predicting in which direction a reaction or process that alters the amount of the species will proceed.

Comment: Take a look at https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Millersville_University/CHEM_341-_Physical_Chemistry_I/07%3A_Mixtures_and_Solutions/7.03%3A_Chemical_Potential

Comment: @IanBush It is the identical link as the OP refers to.  :-)

Comment: "Purely definitional" is the best we could hope for generally, because it is not possible to derive nor proof definitions.

Comment: Whoops. But the OP should still take a look, the very first equation contradicts their assertion that the Gibb's Free Energy  and the chemical potential are the same thing. They even have different dimensions.

Comment: @JohnnySmith The partial molar Gibbs energy of species $i$ is the **same** as the chemical potential of species $i$, i.e. $\mu_i = \overline{g}_i = \left[\dfrac{\partial (ng)}{\partial n_i}\right]_{p,T,n_{k \neq i}}$. You can use either symbol. For your equation, where the fluid is pure and $g$ doesn't depend on composition, the chemical potential is just the Gibbs free energy of that single species $\mu_i = g_i$

Comment: @IanBush You have omitted "molar", referring to the article.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$dG=VdP-SdT-\sum{\mu_in_i}$$So, $$\frac{\partial G}{\partial P}=V$$and $$\frac{\partial G}{\partial n_i}=\mu_i$$So, $$\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial n_i \partial P}=\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial P\partial n_i}=\frac{\partial V}{\partial n_i}=V_{m,i}=\frac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial P}$$

Comment: And the same can be done for T and  -S.

Comment: @Poutnik Yes.  Thanks.  I was hoping that the OP would realize that.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense about how you found the coefficients on $dP$ and $dT$. However, why don't we include the terms $dn_1,dn_2,\dots,dn_k$ (excluding $dn_i$) in the total differential of $\mu_i$?

Comment: The equation assumes constant mixture composition.

Comment: Did you mean $\sum_i\mu_idn_i$ in your first equation ?